# Problem in XCom Enemy Unknown when first item is Attack european alien base

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I encountered the following problem in XCom Enemy Unknown on PS3. In the Mission control screen, I have two options during gameplay: the first one is attack European alien base, the second is "scan for activity". Occasionally, when I scan for activity, a UFO landing site is reported, with now options to intercept the landing site ("send skyranger"), or to ignore. If I decide to intercept, I go to the team preparation screen, but the mission tag says that I am attacking the alien base. I haven't tried to launch the mission, but is it a glitch in the mission name, or a glitch in the selection ?

Has anyone else experienced this behavior?

Comment: why not save the game and try it, see if it takes you to the supply ship or the base.  I suspect its a glitch in the mission name, but I've never played the PS3 version.

Comment: @spartacus good idea. Let me see if I can reproduce it from the last save I had. (I just lost horribly)

Comment: @spartacus: Ok, apparently it's a glitch in the name. I tried and the launched mission is actually an UFO intercept, not the alien base assault. I will answer my own question for future reference.

Comment: Do you mean the "current objective" thing? That's not a mission description; that's the next storyline objective. Earlier in the campaign, it'll say something like "Build the Alien Containment Facility", but you're not sending your troops out into the field to construct an alien containment facility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is showing the current story objective, even if it has nothing to do with the current mission. It's the same on Xbox and PC.

Comment: Yeah, it's just reminding you what your overall goal should be, but the current mission may well be nothing to do with that goal.

Answer (score 1):

In the mission preparation screen it always shows the story related mission in case it is still pending.